# How to acces columns after groupby and agg statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The DataFrame I obtain have a column for each agg element in each column. The format I want is a table with 3 columns (albcircu, mean, count)  not 5.

The code I have is:

```py
data = read_csv_file()
valor = data[['albcircu', 'litros']] 
valor[['albcircu', 'litros']].groupby(valor['albcircu']).agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

A minimum reproducible example could be this:

```py
import pandas as pd
alb = [1800200139, 1800700023, 1800700077, 1800700119, 1800600011, 1800600091, 1800300190, 1800200054, 1802500015, 1800500078, 1800400087, 1800500035, 1800800169, 1800200002, 1800500035, 1800500060, 1800600129, 1800600182, 1802500077, 1800300179]
litros = [400, 500, 500, 452, 1000, 917, 600, 1600, 500, 400, 500, 1500, 444, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 974]
data = pd.DataFrame({'albcircu':alb,'litros':litros})
output = data[['albcircu','litros']].groupby(data['albcircu']).agg(['count','mean'])
output #this is because in jupyter this prints the data output
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshots. It is very unreadable and unsearchable like this.

Comment: I have updated the post  with the three lines of code I use, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC thanks por the advice, I have added a little code that can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multiindex on the columns as a result of the `agg` operation. You can combine them and rename the columns as follows. The idea here is that df.columns will return a list of tuples, so you iterate over that list and combine the tuples.

```
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
```

As an aside, there is an easier way to do the `agg` operation.

```
data.groupby('albcircu').agg({'litros': ['count', 'mean']})
```

Comment: Thak you!!  it is what i was looking for.